# edit css in css folder but there was no anything change in the display

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I was trying to edit css in yii, i opened css folder then editted form.css, but nothing has changed. how can this happen?

Im trying to change file index.php from siteController, and opened the css file in css folder, but all the changes did not reflect in the css file. Really I nedd help!

Comment: clear your browser cache or use Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0):

First convert your application in production/development mode by making some changes in yii entry script.

Changes are:

```
/ Enable debug mode for development environment
  defined( 'YII_DEBUG' ) or define( 'YII_DEBUG', true );

// Specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined( 'YII_TRACE_LEVEL' ) or define( 'YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3 );
```

After this if problem persist you should delete the content of assets folder. I am sure after doing this your problem will be solved.

Comment: i found your script in index.php, on root folder, there are the same..
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

Answer (score 0):

did you re-publish the assets? deleting the content of the assets folder should be enough.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/